# Is there a way that I could implement voice control into my application?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, voice-recognition

I would like to add voice control to my application. When I say "add voice control", I mean the user clicks a button which turns the voice control on, then if the user says a command (such as "Select All"), it performs that command. I have all the code for the application written.

Could somebody give me a suggestion on how I could implement such a feature?

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gp7qK_WodBQ) is the kind of thing I wish to implement, but I've never programmed in VB, so I need some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built in `System.Speech.Recognition` classes.

Check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a) for a comprehensive example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the classes defined in the [System.Speech.Recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx) namespace.